# Vectorizing conditional replacement of a value in a datatable by a value in the next row

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have a need to do the following sort of operation on a large set of data. Here’s a simple version of the problem:

```
dt = data.table(start = c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), end = c(5, 15, 100, 35, 45, 55))
final = 75

print(dt)

for (i in 1:dim(dt)[1]) {
  if (dt[i, end] > final)
    dt[i, end := dt[i+1, start]]
}

print(dt)
```

Output:

```
# initial
   start end
1:     1   5
2:    10  15
3:    20 100
4:    30  35
5:    40  45
6:    50  55

# final
   start end
1:     1   5
2:    10  15
3:    20  30
4:    30  35
5:    40  45
6:    50  55
```

Basically, whenever there is a value in the `end` column that is greater than the `final` variable, I want it replaced with the next `start` value (from the next row).

I want to vectorize that `for` loop somehow, because, as I mentioned, I am doing this on a large set of data (likewise, I’d rather keep it in `data.table`, but if I have to use `dplyr`, that’s fine too). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this :

```
dt$end<- ifelse(dt$end>final,c(dt$start[-1],max(dt$start)),dt$end)

 start end
1:     1   5
2:    10  15
3:    20  30
4:    30  35
5:    40  45
6:    50  55
```

What it does is that for each value of `dt$end`, if the value is greater than final, then it selects the value of start from the next row (or the maximum of start if the problem appears on the last row, as there is no following value). If it is not greater, it keeps the original value.

Thanks to Frank's comment, here is the solution using `data.table`with an add-in to avoid a NA value if the last item of end is greater than final :

```
dt[, end := ifelse(end > final, shift(start, type="lead",fill=max(start)), end)]
```

which gives (changed the last value to 80) :

```
dt = data.table(start = c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), end = c(5, 15, 100, 35, 45, 80))
final = 75
dt[, end := ifelse(end > final, shift(start, type="lead",fill=max(start)), end)]
dt
   start end
1:     1   5
2:    10  15
3:    20  30
4:    30  35
5:    40  45
6:    50  50
```

Explanation of `c(start[-1],max(start))`:

This is (almost) the same as `shift`: you take the column start and remove the first element, so that the new first element is in fact the previous second element and so on, so that creates a shift in your vector. Given that you removed one element, you need to add another : `max(start)`

```
dt$start
[1]  1 10 20 30 40 50

c(dt$start[-1],max(dt$start)) : you take all the values of start except the first + the max
[1] 10 20 30 40 50 50
```

Comment: For reference, the data.table analogue is `dt[, end := ifelse(end > final, shift(start, type="lead"), end)]`

Comment: @Frank : what is the necessary package for shift ? i tried with magic but then I got the error "unused argument (type = "lead")"

Comment: The latest CRAN version of the data.table package added that function. If you have another package that also has a `shift` function (... since it's a common name), then maybe `data.table::shift` will work.

Comment: Thanks, @etienne. This also works: `DT[, end := ifelse(end > final, c(start[-1], max(start)), end)]`. Could someone explain what it does though? I understand the ifelse() function, but what does `c(start[-1], max(start)), end)` do? I will also take a look at the `shift`, thanks @Frank.

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid etienne added an explanation to the answer.